# Send sniffed packets with scapy

Tags: python, scapy, pcap, replay

I am writing a program which uses scapy to read a pcap file. I can operate on each packet with my ***custom*** function, some which I discard and don't want at all. My goal is to do whatever I need to do to a packet and if I need, send it through my **lo** interface where I have a piece of software listening in.

Effectively the problem is, how do I send packet by packet through the **lo** interface?

Comment: Did you try looking at the docs ? Just use `send` or `sendp`

Comment: thanks @Cukic0d, i actually ended up using sendp. It looks like if I use send I am not able to see the packets in wireshark.